# Compare values of common properties of objects in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect

I'm trying to write a method that will compare the 'common properties' (sharing the same name/type) of two objects in Kotlin. Its intended to be used in tests, for comparing 'expected' with 'actual' objects that aren't of the same type.

This is a simplified version on the code so far:

```
val obj1Props = obj1::class.memberProperties
val obj2Props = obj2::class.memberProperties

val commonPropertyPairs  = obj1Props.map { obj1Prop ->
        obj1Prop to obj2Props.find { obj2Prop -> obj1Prop.name == obj2Prop.name } }
    .filter { pair -> pair.second != null }

commonPropertyPairs.forEach { pair ->
  pair.first.get(obj1)
}
```

I'm currently getting this error message under 'pair.first.get' near the bottom:

> out-projected type `KProperty1<out Any, Any?>` prohibits the use of `public abstract fun get(receiver: T): R defined in kotlin.reflect.KProperty1`

I understand that I obviously cannot use abstract methods, what should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `obj1::class.memberProperties` you need to use `SomeClass::class.memberProperties`, e.g.:

```
override fun buildNavItem() {
    val obj1 = "Hello"
    val obj2 = 10
    val obj1Props = String::class.memberProperties
    val obj2Props = Int::class.memberProperties

    val commonPropertyPairs  = obj1Props.map { obj1Prop ->
        obj1Prop to obj2Props.find { obj2Prop -> obj1Prop.name == obj2Prop.name } }
            .filter { pair -> pair.second == null }

    commonPropertyPairs.forEach { pair ->
        pair.first.get(obj1)
    }
}
```

The reason for this difference is that when using the `SomeClass::class` reference, it will necessarily be a class marker representing `SomeClass`, and not one of its possible derived classes, so it is `KClass<SomeClass>`without prediction types.